# If $a = \mathrm {sup}\ B$, how to show that the following holds?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B \subseteq \mathbb R$ be a nonempty set. If $a = \mathrm {sup}\ B$, then it will be the case that for all $n \in \mathbb N$ that an upper bound of $B$ is $$a +\frac {1}{n}$$ while $$a - \frac {1}{n}$$ won't be an upper bound of $B$.

I attempted to prove this using mathematical induction. It is easy to show that the base case for $n = 1$ is true (by definition of supremum). Then, assuming that the property holds for some $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $k \ge 1$, we proceed to show that it holds for $k + 1$. How can we show that $$a - \frac {1}{k + 1} \le a$$ and that  $$a \le a +\frac {1}{k + 1}$$

Comment: Do not understand it exactly. The first inequation — just subtract $a$. The second one — I suppose there is a mistake here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction is not needed here, but rather the definition of supremum. Since $a = \sup B$ is the **least** upper bound on $B$, any other upper bound must be at least as large as $a$. In particular, since

$$a - \frac 1 n < a$$

it cannot be an upper bound for $B$. Likewise, since $$a < a + \frac 1 n$$
$a + 1/n$ is still an upper bound on $B$.

---

This statement really has nothing to do with natural numbers (suggesting that induction won't be fruitful): It's true that

> $a = \sup B$ if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$, $a + \epsilon$ is an upper bound on $B$, and $a - \epsilon$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

If $a + \frac 1 n$ is not  an upper bound of $B$, then there is an element $a'$ in $B$ such that $a' \gt a + \frac 1 n \gt a$ leading to a contradiction since $a$ is an upper bound of $B$.

Similarly, if $a - \frac 1 n$ is an upper bound of $B$ then $a - \frac 1 n \lt a$ contradicting the fact that $a$ is the least upper bound of $B$.

As T. Bongers has suggested induction is not at all required..